# Issues with new express-openid-connect package

Tags: node.js, express, express-openid-connect

I have been trying to use express-openid-connect for the last few days with no success. I am able to get the flow to work when hard coding my params.  However, my goal is to be able to dynamically call auth() depending on the user being logged in.  My initial attempt included calling

```
app.use(auth(functionThatGetsParams()));
```

Using the approach above, express complains that secret is required.  For some reason, the auth call is getting called before anything else is resolved.

I also tried doing a few different ways,

```
app.use((req,res, next)=> process.env.secret = 'hello');
app.use(auth({secret: process.env.secret}));
```

The example above also returns the secret issue.  However, setting process.env.secret outside of app.use, works fine.

My issue seems to be related to the things I do in the app.use block.  The approach I am looking to use is have a call that resolves who my user is and based off of that gets the right settings.

```
app.use(ConnectionResolver.resolve);
```

I use a call similar to the above which is basically a handler that does some async stuff to get the client info and right settings then ends with next().

I would expect that then calling

```
app.use(auth(ConnectionManager.getAuthSettings()));
```

Would return the auth settings I need, but when I debug, it looks like this line gets called before anything else, so then secret is missing as the error says.

One other option I believe I may have seen online is creating a list of auth calls for each client, which I can then use for authentication, but I have not seen any examples of how that works.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this might be possible?  The environment I am in is multi tenant.  So I need to be able to dynamically use a certain auth config depending on the user making the call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the concept of middleware.

the `auth` function, is a middleware factory function, it gets a set of options and returns a middleware function based on those options.

The function passed to the `use` method of the express app, will execute only when an incoming request will arrive.

When you do `app.use(auth(getParams()))` what happens is that when your server is starting, it will call `getParams` function, pass the result to `auth` function which in turn will return the auth middleware function that will be passed to the `app.use` function.

Once a request will arrive, the auth **middleware** (the one returned by the `auth` factory function) will execute.

You don't need to use `auth` conditionally. You should set it up, and then you can use the `requiresAuth` middleware provided by `express-openid-connect` package to protect your paths that requires authorization/authentication.

If your secret is loading asynchronically, wrap your entire express app setup in a bootstrap function, load your secret and only then call the server bootstrap function.

```js
async function loadSecret() {
  //load secret from external source
}

function bootstrapServer(secret) {
  const app = express()
  
  app.use(auth({ ..., secert }))
  
  app.get('protected', requiresAuth(), (req, res) => {
    // your protected route, will automatically return 401 if not authenticated
  })

  app.get('non-protected', (req, res) => {
    // This route will be open to all without authentication
  })
}
```